# Session started but not found in Cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have an application that I work in that is experiencing a problem where randomly a blank page loads.

I've found that the beforeFilter function fires but it never goes into the action of the controller that is being called at that time. I have also found that the session when this happens can not be found. session_status() returns PHP_SESSION_NONE. When the page is reloaded php can magically find the session again and the page loads normally.

Any help is appreciated. If you need/would like more information just let me know.

EDIT:

AppController beforeFilter

```
public function beforeFilter() {

        parent::beforeFilter();

        // Log all access to applictaion
        $this->AccessLog->logPageAccess($this->request, $this->Session);

        // Read the app's desired datetime display and set as view variable for TimeHelper use.
        if(Configure::check('Datetime.dateDisplayFormat')) {
            $timeFormat = Configure::read('Datetime.dateDisplayFormat');
            $this->set(compact('timeFormat'));
        }
    }
```

Session Auth.User when session found

```
array(
    'password' => '*****',
    'id' => '44',
    'role_id' => '5',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password_token' => null,
    'email' => 'user@example.com',
    'email_verified' => true,
    'email_token' => null,
    'email_token_expires' => null,
    'active' => true,
    'is_login_locked' => false,
    'last_login' => '2015-02-04 16:41:47',
    'last_action' => null,
    'created' => '2014-07-07 12:45:46',
    'modified' => '2015-02-04 16:41:47',
    'created_by' => '19',
    'modified_by' => '44',
    'deleted' => false,
    'deleted_date' => null,
    'account_locked' => false,
    'lu_theme_id' => '4',
    'first_name' => 'Joe',
    'last_name' => 'Bloggs',
    'Role' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'User',
        'is_admin' => false
    )
)
```

$_SESSION when not found

```
array()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running an array of servers under a load balancer? I've seen session weirdness in that type of environment before now.

Comment: Our production environments run as such but this issue is occurring on our dev server which is a single server as well.

Comment: Can you paste your beforeFilter function here and also a brief description of what you are storing in Session? i.e. Is it being constructed by the Cake AuthComponent? Should the view that goes blank be accessible by logged in users only or is it unlocked via the beforeFilter(), does this happen all over the place or only on specific controllers / views?

Comment: It happens everywhere in the app. See edit above for requested code.

Comment: I take it you are running the same beforeFilter everywhere? If you run debug do you get anything at all back? For example have you tried putting a test variable and seeing if debug prints this to screen when you get the problem? When the bug occurs do you get a white screen of death? In which case the code has died somewhere. If this is the case I would try commenting out the line which logs the access and seeing if the bug continues - maybe something is falling over here.